# If $A^2=B^2$ and $AB=BA$ then $\det(A+B)=0$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ distinct matrices such that $A^2=B^2$ and $AB=BA$. Prove
>   $\det(A+B)=0$

---

From $A^2=B^2$ and $AB=BA$ we get $(A-B)(A+B)=0_n$ hence $\det(A+B)=0$ or $\det(A-B)=0$.

Now suppose $A+B$ invertible. Then ${(A+B)}^2$ invertible therefore $A^2 + 2AB + B^2$ invertible and, from here, $A^2 + AB$ invertible, hence $A, B$ invertible. I can't get a contradiction for this supposition.

Comment: If $A=B$, then the assumptions do hold, but the conclusion may be false.

Comment: @heptagon Right, I've made the correction

Comment: OK, so I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $A+B$ is invertible, then $(A+B)(A-B)=0$ implies $A-B=0$, so that $A=B$, a contradiction.

(I updated the answer to take into account the update of the question.)

Comment: Embarrassing, it's that simple

Comment: @user1551 OK, let me update it once more to be more precise.